# LDR instruction not executing and causing a Hard Fault

Tags: assembly, arm, cortex-m, kinetis

I've run into an issue that has left me seriously scratching my head. Essentially, after moving to a new processor (with the chip shortage) I'm consistently getting a BusFault related to USB communications.

1. This is the fault panel in my IDE, showing the address causing the fault being 0x0040 0008. [image]
2. Then is the main debugger window.  The callstack suggests that the instruction that caused the fault is at at 0x9340 (below the red line in the disassembly window). This looks plausible as the current value in R2 (left side pane) is indeed 0x0040 0000 and, with an offset of 8, gives us exactly the address in BFAR.
   [image]
3. But how can R2 have 0x0040 0000 in it when, just in the previous instruction, at PC 0x933E, its value is loaded from the address stored in R7, with a 0 bytes offset.
4. Looking at the value in R7, R2 should actually have 0x2000 FF48, which is what the memory view shows us. When I manually stepped through the function in a working instance, that 0x0040 0000 was actually the result of the operation above (ANDS R3, R2). It's almost like the underlined instruction, loading from the address stored in R7, into R2, never got executed.

The function in which this happens is called by the USB interrupt. Processor is a MK24FN1M0VDC12.

I've been battling with this for a few days now (over 40 hours I expect) and only last night I was able to properly observe this behavior. Looking for absolutely any idea, no matter how crazy it might sound. The chips were purchased from a broker, but other than this, all other peripherals work perfectly well. Given that in the process of switching I also had to move from using HS USB to FS USB on the current MCU, I'm hoping it's actually an issue in my code and not something else.

LE: **Initial problem fixed. New ones appeared**

After disabling the instruction/data caching and prefetching, according to Kinetis' errata items, the hard fault no longer occurs in that area of the code. Similarly, after decreasing the core's clock from 120MHz to 96MHz, the faults seem to have stopped altogether. I will update this as I go along.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you certain that the reported `pc` value is actually the address of the faulting instruction in this case?  I'm not completely familiar, but in ARM the pc usually points some bytes ahead of the currently executing instruction, and as a result the rules for what address is saved upon exception are [kind of complicated](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/dui0056/d/handling-processor-exceptions/handling-exceptions-on-thumb-capable-processors/the-return-address?lang=en).  If the faulting instruction were actually 0x9342 then things would make more sense.

Comment: If so, then the bad address `0x00400000` would have been loaded from address `0x2000ff50`.  Does the latter address in fact contain the value `0x00400000`?

Comment: Also, it appears unlikely from the source code, but have you ruled out the possibility that the program branched to 0x9340, instead of executing it following 0x933e?

Comment: I think the actual fault is from 0x9330.  My guess is you are trying to use USB hardware, without starting the clock for this module.  If the USB module is not clocked, it will result in an imprecise bus error.  Ie, the BFAR will point to some instruction after the actual problem.  The [BFSR](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/dui0552/a/cortex-m3-peripherals/system-control-block/configurable-fault-status-register) seems to says this is not the case, but I don't know enough about faulting on this Cortex-m series.  All of the evidence would indicate my case, unless the CPU is damaged?

Comment: 0x932a and 0x933e are identical memory wise.  (I think) the `r7` is holding `ptrUSB_hw` and both are loading offset '0'.  If 0x933e was faulting, then 0x932a would have faulted unless the memory at `r7` is overwritten.  Sorry, `r7` is a stack frame, so you may have a stack overflow or corruption?

Comment: I am curious what you used before?  STM32, Nordic, Microchip, TI or something else?  This clock thing happens on NXP/Freescale IP.  It is to allow better power consumption by turning clocks off to modules when not in use.  However, it often bites you when trying to get modules to function for the first time (and gives puzzling results as you have described).  And did the other vendor not have this clock tree type architecture?

Comment: A few updates:
1. Kinetis K24 has an errata that says you're not supposed to use caching or instruction prefetching  for devices that have flash sizes bigger than 384kB. https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/errata/KINETIS_0M33Z.pdf . So I disable it all and, although it's much more stable now, I'm still getting hard faults in other areas of the code. This runs perfectly without FS USB enabled.

USB clocks seem active, as the device can sometimes communicate without any issues for 30-60seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to have some sort of conclusion on this. After reducing the Kinetis flash clock to 20MHz (from 24Mhz, confirmed using an oscilloscope), the hard fault disappeared. After further investigation into another issue (noisy ADC readings) we believe the problem is actually the design of the chip's power supply lines. Instead of a 3V3 plane with decoupling capacitors close to the pins themselves, our design has a single trace running from all the 5 supply pins to the outside of the chip and then the decoupling capacitors are all placed in parallel there.

We're currently doing another design iteration to confirm that was indeed the problem. Will update this post when that happens. Thanks all for your help!

Comment: Yes, the new design fixed the issue.